# RNFS.exists() always returns FALSE

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

The RNFS.exists() method always returns false, even though the file exists. My file is stored in a manually created folder app/assets

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View,Text,Image,Button} from 'react-native'
import styles from "./styles"
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

class CharacterSelect extends Component{

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        displayView:null
    }
}


async funcy() {
    RNFS.exists(await "@assets/character.json")
    .then((exists) => {
        if (exists){
            console.warn("in the if statement")
        } else {
            console.warn("in the else statement")
        }
    })
}

render() {
    this.funcy()



    const {} = styles
    return(
        <PaperProvider>
        <View style={styles.viewTitle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Welcome to RpgDoIt!</Text>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={require('@assets/titlelogo.png')}/>
        </View>

        {this.state.displayView}
        </PaperProvider>
    )
}
```

}

export default CharacterSelect

Comment: If you mean the android assets, those aren't actually files and can't be accessed via the filesystem-  they need to be accessed via AssetManager.  If this is some off RN concept I've never heard of you can ignore this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't add the storage permission tag into AndroidManifest.xml file, RNFS.exists() will always return false. So you should add this line into your AndroidManifest.xml file.

add this line to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse!! I added this and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />, placed my file into assets under /android/app/src/main/assets and used existsAssets and that seemed to work! However it does not pick up on the file being deleted unless the application is reloaded from command line :/